# How to insert unique ID from subquery into a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL Server tables: `users_flags` and `users`.

`users`:

| user_id | email_address |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | john@company.com |
| 2 | amy@company.com |
| 3 | john@company.com |
| 2 | amy@company.com |

`users_flags`:

| flag_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |

How do I insert all **unique** `user_id` values from the `users` table into the `users_flags` table, using a subquery to filter by `email_address`?

For example, I have a list of email addresses that I need to retrieve the `user_id` for:

```
SELECT user_id FROM users
WHERE email_address IN ('john@company.com',
                        'amy@company.com',
                        'guster@company.com')
```

Normally, I would just use this as a subquery of my `INSERT` statement (I need to hard code the `flag_id`):

```
INSERT INTO users (flag_id, user_id)
SELECT 3,
       user_id
FROM users
WHERE email_address IN ('john@company.com',
                        'amy@company.com',
                        'guster@company.com')
```

However, since my `users` dataset currently has some duplicate data, I need to get only the `DISTINCT` `user_id` records from that table.

I can not use the `DISTINCT` keyword on `user_id` in my subquery, though (invalid syntax). How would I update my `INSERT` statement to account for only unique user IDs?

Comment: e.g.: subquery...

Comment: The right sintax is `SELECT DISTINCT 3, user_id ...`, you have likely typed `SELECT 3, DISTINCT user_id...`

Comment: @JaimeDrq - That is exactly what I was doing wrong,  you are correct. Thank you!

Comment: _has some duplicate data_ FIX that and apply the proper constraints to prevent it. Data quality problems should not be avoided, otherwise every query that uses this information must be written to address this.

Answer (score 0):

use window function row_number()

```
INSERT INTO users (flag_id, user_id)
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT 3 as flag_id,
       user_id,
       row_number() over(partition by user_id order by (select null)) as seq
  FROM users
  WHERE email_address IN ('john@company.com',
                        'amy@company.com',
                        'guster@company.com')) T
WHERE seq = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `select distinct`:

```
INSERT INTO users (flag_id, user_id)
    SELECT DISTINCT 3, user_id
    FROM users
    WHERE email_address IN ('john@company.com',
                            'amy@company.com',
                            'guster@company.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

They're are many solution for this to avoid duplicates, for example:

`NOT EXISTS`

```
INSERT INTO users (flag_id, user_id)
SELECT u.3,
   u.user_id
  FROM users u
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT user_id
                    FROM users u2 
                   WHERE u2.user_id = u.user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with Temp as(

SELECT Distinct user_id FROM users
WHERE email_address IN ('john@company.com',
                    'amy@company.com',
                    'guster@company.com')
)

INSERT INTO users (flag_id, user_id) select 3, user_id from Temp
```

The above solution will work im almost all DBs